# Как объединить значения цвета выдаваемые getcolors

Tags: python, color, rgb

Функция `getcolors` выдает очень много значений, но я хотел бы, чтобы похожие значения по типу `70.70.70` и `71.72.69` объединялись в одно значения которого встречается больше. Можно ли так сделать? Пишу на python.
Вот строчка кода

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test.jpg')
im1= img.convert('RGB').getcolors(10000)
```

Она возвращает очень много значений хотелось бы что бы числа которых RGB отличается на 10 или менее группировались в одно усреднение значение.
Например :
120.30.90 и 123.39.100 группируются, а :120 110 30 и 120 30 110 нет.

Буду рад если поможете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А цель то какая всего этого? Можно применить что-то хитрое, например, кластеризацию. А можно просто округлять компоненты, например, до десятков - это довольно просто и, возможно, этого будет достаточно.

Comment: просто хочу выделять основные цвета .они у меня выделяются ,но там куча одинаковых цветов например : 71.71.71 и 70.70.70 и они занимают место в статистике а еще некоторые не входят в статистику т.к. цвета не много отличаются .

Comment: Ну так вы подумайте, что вам всё-таки нужно - действительно найти "центры тяжести", в которых концентрируются цвета или просто раскидать цвета по фиксированным корзинам.

Comment: найти "центры тяжести"

Comment: Тогда попробуйте кластеризацию, например вот этот метод: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html#sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation